# PHP - Export CSV Function Doesn't Process All Data When Header Isn't Skipped

Tags: php, mysql, csv

We are creating a function that exports data from a table to a CSV then deletes the data from the table. We have created the ability for the user to select if there is a header in the first row of the CSV (yes or no radio buttons). However, when no is selected, the function only runs for the very first row but doesn't continue to loop the other rows. Any ideas on what is missing?

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['user']) {
    header("Location: index.php"); // If session is not set that redirect to Login Page
  }

//set successful imported rows count to 0
$successCount = 0;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$skip = mysqli_real_escape_string($csvDatabase, $_POST['header']);
$colNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($csvDatabase, $_POST['SUIDnumber']);
$colNumber = $colNumber - 1;

//get filename
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {
for($i=0; $i<count($filename); $i++) {
    $file = $filename[$i];
    //open file in read only
    $files = fopen($file, "r");
    //skips first line
    if ($skip === "yes") {
      fgetcsv($files, 10000, ","); 
    }
    //get data from csv & uses comma to find separate values
        while (($getData = fgetcsv($files, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
         {
            $fail = FALSE;
            //store SUID from pre-set line in csv
            $suid = $getData[$colNumber];
            if (strlen($suid) === 9 && ctype_digit($suid) ) {
            // start ldap look up
            $basedn="***";

            //Connect to server
            $ds=ldap_connect("***");

            if ($ds) {
                //bind with our special account that retrieves more attributes
                $ldaprdn  = '***';     // ldap rdn or dn
                $ldappass = '**';  // associated password
                $r=ldap_bind($ds,$ldaprdn,$ldappass);    // this is an authenticated bind
                if (substr($suid, 0, 1) === ";" || is_numeric($suid)) {
                        if ($r) {
                            //filter to all objectclasses that the SUID we are looking for
                            $filter = "(&(objectClass=*)(syrEduSUID={$suid}))";

                            //We are only interested in retrieving these attributes
                            $justthese = array("displayName", "syrEduLevel", "syrEduProgramDesc", "syrEduProgram", "mail", "eduPersonPrimaryAffiliation", "eduPersonAffiliation", "uid" );

                            // Search SUID
                            $sr=ldap_search($ds, $basedn, $filter, $justthese );

                                $entry = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
                                // if we have only one result, return the values, if not, we have a problem

                                if ($entry["count"] == 1) {
                                // get student name and email from suid

                                $studentName = mysqli_real_escape_string($csvDatabase, $entry[0]['displayname'][0]);
                                $studentEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($csvDatabase, $entry[0]['mail'][0]);
                                $studentAffiliation = mysqli_real_escape_string($csvDatabase, $entry[0]['edupersonprimaryaffiliation'][0]);
                                $studentProgram = mysqli_real_escape_string($csvDatabase, $entry[0]['syreduprogramdesc'][0]);
                                $studentEduLevel = mysqli_real_escape_string($csvDatabase, $entry[0]['syredulevel'][0]);
                                $netID = mysqli_real_escape_string($csvDatabase, $entry[0]['uid'][0]);

                                    $successCount++;

                                // close ldap
                                ldap_close($ds);

                                } else {
                                    $msg  = "Ldap search returned 0 or more than one result";
                                    $fail = TRUE;
                                }

                    }
                } else {
                    $msg  = "Bind failed";
                    $fail = TRUE;
                }
            } else {
                $msg  = "LDAP connection failed";
                $fail = TRUE;
            }

                        //split full name
                        $studentName = trim($studentName);
                        $last_name = (strpos($studentName, ' ') === false) ? '' : preg_replace('#.*\s([\w-]*)$#', '$1', $studentName);
                        $first_name = trim( preg_replace('#'.$last_name.'#', '', $studentName ) );

                        //inserts data into import table
                        $sql = "INSERT into import (suid, firstName, lastName, studentEmail, studentAffiliation, studentProgram, studentEduLevel, netID) values ('$suid', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$studentEmail', '$studentAffiliation', '$studentProgram', '$studentEduLevel', '$netID')";
                        if (!$fail) {

                            if (mysqli_query($csvDatabase, $sql)) {
                                    //once imported properly, export csv
                            } else {
                                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($csvDatabase);
                            }
                         }
                }
        }

    //closes file    
    fclose($files);
    $query = "SELECT suid, firstName, lastName, studentEmail, studentAffiliation, studentProgram, studentEduLevel from import ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT {$successCount}";  
                              $result = mysqli_query($csvDatabase, $query); 
                                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                      header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
                                      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data-export.csv'); 
                                        $output = fopen("php://output", "w"); 
                                        $headers = array('SUID', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Student Email', 'Student Affiliation', 'studentProgram', 'Student Edu Level');
                                        fputcsv($output, $headers); 
                                         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
                                      {  
                                             fputcsv($output, $row);
                                      }  
                                      fclose($output); 
                                        //then delete records in database
                                    $deletesql = "DELETE FROM import ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$successCount}";
                                        if (mysqli_query($csvDatabase, $deletesql)) {
                                            //echo "Record deleted successfully";
                                        } else {
                                            echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($csvDatabase);
                                        }

                            }
     }
} else {
    echo "You did not upload a CSV file or the CSV file is blank.";
}
} else {
?>
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>CSV Import</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
</head>
<body>

 <!-- nav -->
<div class="top-bar">
<div class="top-bar-left">
<ul class="menu">
</ul>
</div>
<div class="top-bar-right">
</div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="margin-top: 5%;">

    <div class="medium-12 columns">

    <form name="upload_excel" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h3>Import CSVs for Student Data</h3>
            <div class="callout secondary">
            <fieldset class="large-4 cell">
            <legend>Does the CSV have a header in the first row?</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="header" value="yes" id="yesHeader"><label for="yesHeader">Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" name="header" value="no" id="noHeader"><label for="noHeader">No</label>
          </fieldset>
            <label for="SUIDnumber">
              What number column is the SUID field in?
              <input type="number" value="" id="SUIDnumber" name="SUIDnumber" required>
            </label>
            <p>Upload your CSV(s) with SUIDs. You will then be prompted to download the exported data.</p>
            <input type="file" id="files" name="file[]" accept=".csv" multiple><br>
            <input type="submit" class="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Import CSV">
                </div>
        </form>


</div>
  </div>

<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The logic for $skip seems okay to me. Are you sure that's where the problem is? Could you maybe test it using a sample file with and without the header (and share the contents of that file)?

Comment: @Aioros Using a file with a header works perfectly, but any file without a header (the data starting on that line) either goes to a blank page or just goes through the first line (depending on the file).

Comment: Yes, I understand, but it would still be useful to have a sample file with and without a header so that we could test it.

Comment: @Aioros With header: https://ufile.io/ldd4b
Without header: https://ufile.io/uiz3p

Comment: Well, they seem to be working ok for me. The only thing I would suggest is adding `ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);` at the beginning, just in case the no-header files actually have some different line ending style.

Comment: @Aioros That seemed to fix the issue on my end. Thank you!